# querying tables for prerequisite course

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a database with tables as shown in the image. the fields under prerequisite are (pre- previous course id and following- following course id). i want to get the "following courses" list from course table where their "previous course" grade is 'F' and display them with disabled checkbox. and then show "previous courses" list with grade 'F' as checkbox.
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsMSt.jpg)

I tried to join the tables like the following, but it didnt work.

```
    SELECT
prerequisite.id,
prerequisite.following,
`result`.course_id,
`result`.grade,
`result`.approved,
`result`.student_id,
course.course_credit,
course.course_name,
course.id_course,
prerequisite.pre,
student.stu_id
FROM prerequisite
INNER JOIN `result` ON prerequisite.pre = `result`.course_id
INNER JOIN course ON course.id_course = prerequisite.pre
INNER JOIN student ON student.stu_id = `result`.student_id
WHERE (`result`.grade ='F')
```

Comment: when you say it didn't work can you elaborate a bit more? what did the output look like - why did it not work? did mysql throw an error? did it simply return 0 rows?

I suppose first thing to try would be to start by removing all of the joins and begin joining the tables one at a time to see if one of those inner joins is causing 0 records to return.

Comment: i mean the query always returns a course name for the "following course", what i need is to to return the "following course" only if the "pre course" result is "F".

Comment: Add the condition to the first inner join to only return those with grade ='F'

Comment: And result.grade ='F'